# How to get df linux command output always in GB

Tags: linux, linux-disk-free

How to get df linux command output always in GB always? 
ie. I want below 34MB to be displayed in GBs

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/ttt/pda1              21G   20G   34M 100% /
```

How can this be achieved ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can use the `-B` option.

[Man page of df](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?df):

> -B, --block-size=SIZE use SIZE-byte blocks

All together,

```
df -BG
```

Answer (score 6):

If you also want it to be a command you can reference without remembering the arguments, you could simply alias it:

```
alias df-gb='df -BG'
```

So if you type:

```
df-gb
```

into a terminal, you'll get your intended output of the disk usage in GB.

EDIT: or even use just `df -h` to get it in a standard, human readable format.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/df-examples/

Comment: -g is not an valid option

Comment: @Aryan Ah, well, perhaps then using fedorqui suggestion of `df -BG` and aliasing that for ease of use.

Comment: @Aryan I've updated my answer to reflect the correction of my derp.